# How to set the default expand limit to 4 for expandablelistview ?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, expandablelistview

I am working with expandablelistview. I have to expand the group listview to 4 by default. Is it possible to achieve that?.

Answer (score 1):

You can define fixed value in group list-view like below:

```
private void prepareListData() {
        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        // Adding parent data
        listDataHeader.add("first");
        listDataHeader.add("second");
        listDataHeader.add("third");
        listDataHeader.add("fourth");

        // Adding child data
        List<String> first = new ArrayList<String>();
        first.add("The Shawshank Redemption");
        first.add("The Godfather");
        first.add("The Godfather: Part II");
        first.add("Pulp Fiction");
        first.add("The Good, the Bad and the Ugly");
        first.add("The Dark Knight");
        first.add("12 Angry Men");

        List<String> second = new ArrayList<String>();
        second.add("The Conjuring");
        second.add("Despicable Me 2");
        second.add("Turbo");
        second.add("Grown Ups 2");
        second.add("Red 2");
        second.add("The Wolverine");

        List<String> third = new ArrayList<String>();
        third.add("2 Guns");
        third.add("The Smurfs 2");
        third.add("The Spectacular Now");
        third.add("The Canyons");
        third.add("Europa Report");

        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), first); // Header, Child data
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), second);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), third);
    }
```

Comment: This is not going to help what i required.

Comment: u want list view display 4 child  defaultly ..? right

Comment: exactly. When it expand show the all child of particular group.

Comment: if child length <4 then also u want default 4 length ..Ans               List<String> child = new ArrayList<String>();
        child.add("");
        child.add("");
        child.add("");
        child.add("");
        child.add("");

Comment: and when u want add value in that particular child..then u can set that value in arralist like  child.set(possition,value); after that refresh list so add your value in perticular position